# Git: after commiting new files, I cannot commit, because of »branch up to date«-message

Tags: git, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

this is one of my first postings on stackoverflow. I hope I explain my problem clearly for you.

I have a local git repo and I work with a git repo on drupal.org (I have the maintainer-permissions). I've followed up the git instructions on my project-page (cloning, switching to branch..). But when I add new files to a subfolder of this project and then want to push (on defining the correct origin - like in the git-instructions on drupal.org),

git push -u origin 6.x-1.x

so I get the message

Branch 6.x-1.x set up to track remote branch 6.x-1.x from origin.
Everything up-to-date

Why I cannot push my new files? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> Why I cannot push my new files? What I'm doing wrong?

Make sure to ADD your new files first:

```
git add FILENAME/PATH
```

or to add all files;

```
git add .
```

Or add newly added files AND commit using '-am' switch:

```
git commit -am "your message goes here"
```

After that, you can run your push command:

```
git push -u origin 6.x-1.x
```

Comment: Also, use git status for checking what actually will be committed and what won't.

Comment: I am also new to git, and the stagging area what not obvious. [You could check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676450/eclipse-git-what-does-staged-mean).

Comment: I've noticed by trying to add a single file, that there was a submodule. I had to remove it. The tutorial at http://chrisjean.com/2009/04/20/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/ was helpful for that.