# Does cloning a repository using Git creates two copies of it on our local machines?

Tags: git, visual-studio, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using Git for version controlling and Source Tree client. I make some changes to **file A** in Visual Studio and save the changes, but I do not commit those changes to my local repository. So there will be two copies of **file A** now. So does this mean there will be two copies of a cloned repository?(one copy is the local branch and other one is the copy we open it in visual studio or any editor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, both (Visual Studio and sourceTree) should reference the [same working tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3690796/6309) (the folder in which your git repo is checked out)

When you modify and save `fileA` in Visual Studio, it will appear in SourceTree as modified (you would need to add and commit).

[image: working tree]

Comment: what does staging area mean here?

Comment: @Suraj "staging" is another name for the [git index](http://schacon.github.io/gitbook/7_the_git_index.html).

Comment: @Suraj index: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/676454/6309 and http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/10/git-tip-of-week-understanding-index.html